# Creating conda env from .yml - packages doesn't download

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda

I have some serious problems with creating virtual env for conda. Whole process does not return errors, but packages that are supposed to be present - are not.

Here is my yml file:

```
name: linuxenv
channels:
  - defaults
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - _libgcc_mutex=0.1=main
  - blas=1.0=mkl
  - ca-certificates=2019.5.15=0
  - certifi=2019.6.16=py27_0
  - pip=19.1.1=py27_0
  - setuptools=41.0.1=py27_0
  - wheel=0.33.4=py27_0
  - pip:
      - libstdcxx-ng==9.1.0=hdf63c60_0
      - scipy==1.2.1=py27h7c811a0_0
      - libgfortran-ng==7.3.0=hdf63c60_0
      - libffi==3.2.1=hd88cf55_4
      - zlib==1.2.11=h7b6447c_3
      - tk==8.6.8=hbc83047_0
      - numpy==1.16.4=py27h7e9f1db_0
      - ncurses==6.1=he6710b0_1
      - openssl==1.1.1c=h7b6447c_1
      - readline==7.0=h7b6447c_5
      - mkl==2019.4=243
      - python==2.7.16=h9bab390_0
      - sqlite==3.28.0=h7b6447c_0
      - intel-openmp==2019.4=243
      - scikit-learn==0.20.3=py27hd81dba3_0
      - libgcc-ng==9.1.0=hdf63c60_0
      - mkl_fft==1.0.12=py27ha843d7b_0
      - numpy-base==1.16.4=py27hde5b4d6_0
      - libedit==3.1.20181209=hc058e9b_0
      - mkl_random==1.0.2=py27hd81dba3_0
```

While here is the outcome:

```
(linuxenv) C:\Users\szyna>conda list
# packages in environment at C:\Users\szyna\Anaconda3\envs\linuxenv:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                        main
blas                      1.0                         mkl
ca-certificates           2019.5.15                     0
certifi                   2019.6.16                py27_0
pip                       19.1.1                   py27_0
python                    2.7.16               hcb6e200_0
setuptools                41.0.1                   py27_0
sqlite                    3.28.0               h0c8e037_0
vc                        9                    h7299396_1
vs2008_runtime            9.00.30729.1         hfaea7d5_1
wheel                     0.33.4                   py27_0
wincertstore              0.2              py27hf04cefb_0
```

As I said, executin `conda create` does not return any error, only that message

```
Ran pip subprocess with arguments:
['C:\\Users\\szyna\\Anaconda3\\envs\\linuxenv\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '-U', '-r', 'C:\\Users\\szyna\\Desktop\\condaenv.z8p1vx1r.requirements.txt']
Pip subprocess output:
Collecting libstdcxx-ng==9.1.0=hdf63c60_0 (from -r C:\Users\szyna\Desktop\condaenv.z8p1vx1r.requirements.txt (line 1))
```

Does any of You have an idea what to do?

Comment: What command are you using to create the environment?

Comment: conda env create -f file.yml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That YAML file is not (semantically) valid - many of the packages you have nested under `pip` are not available from PyPI (e.g., `mkl`, `lib*`).  Plus, the all the build info (e.g., `...=hdf*`) corresponds to Anaconda Cloud-hosted packages. If you generated this YAML with `conda export` or similar, you should [report this as a bug](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues).

As for getting it working, if there is a specific package you know is only available through PyPI, then keep that under the `- pip:` list; otherwise, delete the `- pip:` line, and remove the indentation on the all the subsequent lines.

Also, just FYI, mixing PyPI and Conda is hairy - best practice seems to be only resorting to PyPI if the package is completely unavailable through Anaconda Cloud channels.  For more info, see ["Using Pip in a Conda Environment"](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/).

Comment: Indeed I've got that yaml with conda export. Thank you very much.